# Handling encrypted request depending on cert trust state using mitmproxy

Tags: proxy, mitmproxy

I've read a lot of related topics in the net, but I still don't have an answer to my question.

Is it possible to implement flow described below?

Proxy receive request.

- If request is encrypted and proxy cert is trusted then intercept.
- If request is not encrypted, then intercept.
- If request is encrypted and proxy cert is NOT trusted then pass it through without interception.

This behaviour should be default for all traffic going through the proxy.

It'd be also really nice to be able to get all possible info for passing encrypted requests (src and dst ip addresses etc.). Basically the same info which I can get with fiddler.

Answer (score 1):

Not really. The main problem is that mitmproxy can not know if proxy cert is trusted by the client or not.

In the SSL/TLS protocol client starts with the CLIENT_HELLO and in response the server (in this case motmproxy) sends back the SERVER_HELLO message containing the generated server certificate.

The client now checks if the received server certificate is trusted. If not the connection is terminated. As far as I know the SSL/TLS spec does not define how to do so. Sems clients end back an SSL_ALERT message, other simply drop the connection, and a third group continues the SSL/TLS handshake but have certain internal values set in a way that always let the handshake fail.

There is a mitmproxy script that tries to identify connections that were not successful and then if the client asks for the same domain a second time bypasses interception.
Of course this requires that the client resends requests which is not always the case.
https://github.com/sociam/x-ray/blob/master/mitmproxy/examples/tls_passthrough.py

Comment: Hi Robert! Thank you very much for the answer.
Guess I've found script you mentioned here https://github.com/sociam/x-ray/blob/master/mitmproxy/examples/tls_passthrough.py
Now I have two questions related to your answer and original question.
1. If connection can't be handled as I described then how for example Fiddler handle similar cases? I can see all the requests in it when part of requests are encripted. 
2. How can I use mantioned script in case it in actual script with request interceptors? I'd really appriciate it if you have some example.

Comment: Fiddler Classis (the newer Fiddler Everywhere I don't like) has to states: Interception enabled or disabled (not considering that you can disable interception on a per-request basis in Fiddler script). If you have interception enabled in Fiddler and the client does not trust the proxy certificate or performs cert pinning you will only see `CONNECT <dnsname>` entries, nothing more. How to use the `tls_passthrough.py` with mitmproxy is documented in the comment section of the file itself.